# Add unique id to Preview URL

Tags: functions, urls, cache, previews

Is there an easy way to append a unique ID to the preview URL when the preview button is clicked by a user?

So this: http://example.com/news/1/title/?preview=true

Becomes: http://example.com/news/1/title/?preview=true&v={unique_id}

I ask because our setup caches heavily on the server-side so when updating it takes a while for the changes to show up in the preview. Manually adding a parameter to the end of the URL allows the changes to show up immediately.

I tried searching for a plugin but didn't have any luck. Is there a way to do this by adding a custom function in functions.php?

Comment: Can you provide some more details ? Like which theme & plugin you are using ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `preview_post_link` filter to modify the preview URL:

```
function wpa_preview_link( $preview_link ){
    return $preview_link . '&v=' . uniqid();
}
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', 'wpa_preview_link' );
```